# flutter-web: build_runner getter 'typeArguments' isn't defined for the class 'Annotation' error

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In my web flutter project,I am trying to build it:

```
flutter  packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

But I don't know why I got this error:

```
Failed to precompile build_runner:build_runner:
../../../Sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dart_style-1.3.14/lib/src/source_visitor.dart:302:16: Error: The getter 'typeArguments' isn't defined for the class 'Annotation'.
 - 'Annotation' is from 'package:analyzer/dart/ast/ast.dart' ('../../../Sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-0.40.4/lib/dart/ast/ast.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'typeArguments'.
    visit(node.typeArguments);
```

I am sure It was OK before and **analyzer-0.40.4** was ok, although with changing of analyzer I sill got this error. I am using SDK version 2.7.0:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: 0.40.4
  build_resolvers: '1.4.4'
```

This is flutter doctor:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.24.0-10.2.pre, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)                                                                                                                                                                                      [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0-rc1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

I didn't migrate into new flutter version yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know It is usful or not But I finally fix the problem and I put my solution to may help some guys:

This is all the change :

```
dependency_overrides:
  # analyzer: 0.40.4  // comment this
  build_resolvers: '1.4.2' // this

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: 1.10.4 // this
```